# How Duplicate File search is implemented in Gemini For Mac os

Tags: macos, filesystems

I tried to search for Duplicate files in my mac machine via command line.
This process took almost half an hour for 10 gb Data files whereas Gemini and cleanmymac apps takes lesser time to find the files.
So my point here is how this fastness is achieved in these apps,what is the concept behind it?, in which language code is written.

I tried googling for information but didnot get anything related to duplicate finder.

if you have any ideas please input them here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Gemini locates files with equal size, than it uses it’s own hash-like type-dependent algorithm to compare files content. That algorithm is not 100% accurate but much more quick than classical hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted support, asking them what algorithm they use. Their response was that they compare parts of each file to each other, rather than the whole file or doing a hash. As a result, they can only check maybe 5% (or less) of each file that's reasonably similar in size to each other, and get a reasonably accurate result. Using this method, they don't have to pay the cost of comparing the whole file OR the cost of hashing files. They could be even more accurate, if they used this method for the initial comparison, and then did full comparisons among the potential matches.

Using this method, files that are minor variants of each other may be detected as identical. For example, I've had two songs (original mix and VIP mix) that counted as the same. I also had two images, one with a watermark and one without, listed as identical. In both these cases, the algorithm just happened to pick parts of the file that were identical across the two files.